# Finding euclidean distance between coordinates in python

Tags: python, pdist

I have a problem with pdist function in python. I have coordinates of points that I want to find the distance between them but it does not consider them as coordinates and find distance between two points rather than coordinate (it consider coordinates as decimal numbers rather than coordinates). I could not find anything so far of how to fix this problem. Any help is appreciated. In other words, should I do any transformation on my coordinates? Here is a sample code:

```
    p1=[39.1653, -86.5264]
    p2=[39.704166670000049, -86.399444439999826]
    X=[p1[0],p2[0]]
    Y=[p1[1],p2[1]]
    spdist.pdist(zip(X,Y), 'euclidean')
```

The result it gives me is 0.55361991 miles but when I put the coordinates in google map, it give me 42 miles.

Thanks

Comment: can you post your code since you seem to have written some?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to do, post some code about what you have tried to do, some examples ...

Comment: Thanks. added some code to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate distance from decimal coordinates if you know the formula that's involved.  There's one for [rectangular coordinate systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance); another for [spherical coordinate systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula).

If the Python built in function takes in point parameters, why not wrap your decimal values as points before calling the function?

Comment: Thank you for the comment but I dont exactly get what you meant. I added some code to the question. Could you please dive me some hint on that?

Comment: Those look like lat/lon values.  Those aren't calculated in a Euclidean space; those are in a Spherical Earth coordinate system with a radius of 3,959 miles.

Comment: In that case, should I do any transformation so I can use euclidean distance in python?

Comment: No, rectangular and spherical coordinate systems are entirely different.  You should see if that function takes a 'spherical' argument and perhaps a radius.  You should dig into the docs for that function to understand better what it's doing rather than thrashing around.

Comment: I undrestand. Thank you